# Regression on a triangular shaped region of points representing a symmetric relation

Tags: regression

I plotted a set of about 200,000 points and got a triangular shaped region.  The shape is roughly like the triangle made by the points $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$.  My points have the property that if $(a,b)$ is a member of the set, then $(b,a)$ is also a member.  I wanted to do a regression on the variable associated with the second coordinate y on the variable associated with the first coordinate x. I did a linear regression but I'm bothered by the fact that the region is shaped nothing like a line.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**: The points represent a type of game.  For each player i and j, i can attack j or j can attack i.  The points are produced by looking at (number of times where i attacks j,  of times j attacks i) for all pairs i and j.  This is the reason that we get (a,b) being a member of my set if (b,a) is a member.  I felt that the triangle region suggests that players who don't attack enough have a greater chance of being attacked.  Just to emphasize, my points fill the whole region bounded by a triangle similar to (1,0), (0,1) and (0,0), not necessarily uniformly.

**Second Edit**:The region is shaped like the triangle I mentioned but bigger.  Lets say for arguments sake, it roughly looks like the triangle (1000,0), (0,1000), (0,0).  There are a few scattered points outside the triangle and the triangle itself is not completely filled out.

My goal is to characterize or relate the number of attacks that i makes on j to the number of attacks that j makes on i.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. In your case, for the tuple (a,b), a and b are both observation (may be missing)?

Comment: *Why* did you want to do a regression of one coordinate on the other? The better way to do this depends on what is is you're trying to do. What's the aim? What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: Post-edit: Your statements together seems to imply that the number of times *i* attacks *j* is always either 0 or 1. And that if *i* attacks *j* then *j* attacks *i*. So relating the number of attackes that *i* makes on *j* to the number *j* makes on *i* seems trivial. Sorry, I'm obviously not understanding something here.

Comment: @onestop: Thanks.  Good point.  I was sloppy in my description there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may, after all this time, finally have understood the question.  The data, if I'm correct, are a set of tuples $(i, j, y(i,j))$ where $i$ is one player, $j \ne i$ is another player, and $y(i,j)$ is the number of attacks of $i$ on $j$.  In this notation the objective is to relate $y(i,j)$ to $y(j,i)$.  There are some natural ways to do this, including:

1. Analyze the data set $\{(y(i,j), y(j,i))\}$ by means of a scatterplot or PCA (to find the principal eigenvalue).  Note this is *not* a regression situation because both components of each ordered pair are observed: neither can be considered under the control of an experimenter nor observed without error.  It is this scatterplot, I believe, that appears triangular.  This already suggests that any attempt to describe it succinctly, such as by means of a principal direction, is doomed.
2. Model $y(i,j)$ in terms of characteristics of $i$ and $j$.  This is a classic regression situation.  The solution provides an indirect, but possibly powerful, way to relate $y(i,j)$ to $y(j,i)$.

   In this case, also consider re-expressing the data in terms of *relative* numbers of attacks.  That is, instead of using $y(i,j)$ use $x(i,j) = y(i,j)/\sum_{j}{y(i,j)}$.